# Anonymous accounts on PayPal

Tags: paypal

I know it's not allowed on PayPal to do that, but here's the thing:

So here's what I did: I made an alt account on PayPal and named it "anonymous payer" and used my phone number (my personal one just said "add a phone number for extra security after that) and then it was okay. My alt was okay. I paid some money through prepaid cards to some people to buy commissions before closing that account and making another one to pay someone anonymously again and then closing that one too. However a few days later I make another alt account on PayPal and guess what? PayPal LIMITS my accounts INSTANTLY after I create them. And after a few unsuccessful PayPal anonymous account creations, they start PERMANENTLY LIMITING my accounts INSTANTLY AFTER CREATION.

Like all I wanna do in these accounts is send money to people for commissions via GIFT CARDS and no balance and I don't want to show my IRL name to them because it's personal. Also, some of them don't want to take invoices.

Can someone help out? I have to wait some time before I can make/use temporary anonymous accounts on PayPal again right?

Comment: "_I know it's not allowed ... they start PERMANENTLY LIMITING my accounts ... Can someone help out?_" Perhaps stop doing things you know are not allowed?

Comment: "If it hurts when you do that, stop doing that."

Answer (score 9):

PayPal, as you say you are aware, does not allow anonymous accounts.  This is because, as a business that transfers money from one person to another, just about every government of a country PayPal does business in requires that it know something about its customers to be able to ensure they aren't involved in money laundering or some other crime.  When you use your information to do something suspicious, PayPal responds by closing your accounts.

My guess is that PayPal has permanently added your details to a block list so you won't be able to open new accounts in the future.  It is conceivable that the block is only temporary and you'd be able to open a new account in a month (which, just to point out, would still violate PayPal's terms of service).  You may be able to contact PayPal support to find out how long you are banned but I doubt they will be interested in helping you continue to circumvent the controls they have in place.

Comment: Okay, but am I gonna be arrested or will the FBI find out about this? Since it's faking identity and that's illegal